# c# LINQ: Filter List of Files based on File Size

Tags: c#, linq

I need some help using LINQ to filer a list of files based on the file size. I have some code but it's using file.length instead of FileInfo(file).length. I don't know how to implement an object 'FileInfo' in the expression. HELP?

```
        {            
            IEnumerable<string> result = "*.ini,*.log,*.txt"
            .SelectMany(x => Directory.GetFiles("c:\logs", x, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                            ;

            result = result
                .Where(x => (x.Length) > "500000")

               ;

       }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this.

Using a DirectoryInfo, the GetFiles will return a collection of FileInfo instead of strings.

```
new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\logs")
    .GetFiles("*.ini,*.log,*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(f => f.Length > 500000);
```

Of course you would always create FileInfo inline if you wanted to.

If you just wanted the filenames back..

```
IEnumerable<string> results = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\logs")
    .GetFiles("*.ini,*.log,*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(f => f.Length > 500000)
    .Select(f => f.FullName);
```

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with your searchpattern :)

Comment: @Zion, glad it worked for you!   @CasperT, I didn't run the code and just used the example code provided for the pattern, not 100% if it is accurate or not.

Comment: Look at this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328752(VS.71,loband).aspx

Under "Remarks".

You can only apply a search pattern for one extension in most cases

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. Searchpattern can not check up on multiple extensions.

See this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328752(VS.71,loband).aspx
Basicly these are your searchpattern tools:

- "*" Zero or more characters.
- "?" Exactly one character

There is no separator such as "OR", sadly.

You should instead use a regex pattern:

```
Regex filepattern = new Regex(".log|.txt|.ini");

var test = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\")
    .GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(f => f.Length > 0 && filepattern.IsMatch(f.FullName));
```

To illustrate what Quintin Robinson is talking about:

```
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
    var test = dir
        .GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        .Concat(dir.GetFiles("*.log", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        .Concat(dir.GetFiles("*.ini", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        .Where(f => f.Length > 0);
```

He believes that GetFiles is heavily optimized and it would be faster - especially with a directory with a lot files. I have not benchmarked it and really don't know which is fastest :)

Both methods works. I have tested them and they give the same result

Comment: You could also concat the results of calls to GetFiles and not have to perform the regex match per file.  I would like to believe the filtering on the call to GetFiles is optimized although I can't say for certain.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that :)

Comment: But no matter what, wouldn't each file be compared to a pattern in one way or the other?

Comment: To Concat you could do something along the lines of retaining the instance of the directory info and then `var foundItems = info.GetFiles(filter1).Concat(info.GetFiles(filter2))...` etc. (obviously pseudo).  Anyway it would have to do some filtering and that is why I said I'm not sure of the differences but I would imagine that the GetFiles relies on some native optimized routines.

Comment: I think you should have phrased it as "Throw me a freakin' bone here!".  Although I +1'd you anyway.