# Identify the first table in docx and print which are the documents in a directory contains table in it using c#

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

I need to check all files(especially "*.docx") from a directory with size of about 10 GB and filter the names of the document with tables in it. For each file in the directory I need to iterate through Document elements of file to find out if the opened document has a table. I need to get this done in C#. I am from testing domain but they gave me development kind of task. Please help

Comment: We are a Q/A, [tour]. You are giving us requirement like if it was a freelancer platform.
I will recommend reading [ask], and [mre]. If you don't know where to start its just because you didn't specify enought your requirement. Do it step by step. First [search the document with your extention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152157/find-a-file-with-a-certain-extension-in-folder), check it size https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750590, etc etc..

Comment: Do it step by step, and come back when you have a specific question. I really recommend giving [ask] a try . On those broad requirement It will help the specification and finding the next step.

Comment: using System;
using System.IO;


namespace proactivetable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Data", "*.docx",
                 SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string name in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }


        }
    }       -I have get all of the files from the directory next step is I have to check for Tables in it .If there is a table I should note the name of the docx seperately.

Comment: And do each step independantly. don't try to look for a table on a brunch of file with the extention etc. Take one file with only a table or a few simple tables. And use that to focus on "find table in docx C#". Always try to narrow down things into [mre]. This part should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240933/extract-table-from-docx. with  `Any()`

Comment: May you use the [edit] button and add those information in the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# LINQ: Filter List of Files based on File Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494602/c-sharp-linq-filter-list-of-files-based-on-file-size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` nuget package to access docx files and find the table inside each file.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var files = FindFilesWithTable("<path_to_directory>");

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            }
    }

    static List<string> FindFilesWithTable(string directory)
    {
        // filter all docx files
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.docx");
        var filesWithTable = new List<string>();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                // open file in read only mode
                using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, false))
                {
                    // find the first table in the document.  
                    var hasTable = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>().Any();
                    if (hasTable)
                    {
                        filesWithTable.Add(file);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot process {0}: {1}", file, ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return filesWithTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will use `DirectoryInfo` instead cause it return `FileInfo` usefull for filtering on size.
`var result =  new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\path")
    .GetFiles("*.extention", SearchOption.MySearchoption)
    .Where(f => f.Length >  10_737_418_240)
 .Where({using(){ return hasfile}})
 .Select(x=> x.Name)`

Comment: @DragandDrop I thought that the size of the directory is about 10 GB.

Comment: System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'Central Directory corrupt-It caused this exception.   {using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, false))}--for this line

Comment: @shiva Do you access local or network directory?

Comment: @user2250152 Local Directory.

Comment: @shiva, Time to try to isolate the issue. Create an not corrupted doc. pass it path directly to this line and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @DragandDrop---IOException: An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file. : 'D:\Data\DefectID_SD12065_1.docx'
This was the error

Comment: @shiva You can wrap using (word...) {} in try-catch blocks and you will see how many files cannot be processed. I've edited answer

Comment: @user2250152The program '[8868] proactive table.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program ran error free but output is not fetched.

Comment: @DragandDropThanks to u man!! U guys are awesome and the replys are real quick